# Rewriterule or 301 redirect with variable at the end

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need a quite dificult thing. Almost for me...
I need a 301 redirect or a rewriterule to do next:
Transform this URL:
/productos/carro/producto.asp?IdDetalle=var
to this
/producto.php?IdProducto=var

Where var is a number I need to stay at the end url to do a REQUEST to it.

Thanks all.

Comment: If you have the helpful answer - accept it (click on the checkmark button under answer's votes counter). It will mark the question as solved and add you 2 points of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_rewrite, you can put these rules in the htaccess file in your document root or in your server/vhost config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)IdDetalle=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?productos/carro/producto.asp$ /producto.php?%1IdProducto=%2 [L,R=301]
```